# Does firebase make a network request for every admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a firebase client(browser). I also have a backend server that I identify the user is signed in using the firebase token.

With following [Firebase's docs Verify ID tokens using the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), I am *successfully* using `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)` to verify the token on my node server.

However, one thing concerns me. I know that firebase uses a cert to verify the tokens. Does this mean that everytime I invoke `admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)` a outgoing network request/network transaction is made from my node server? I am concerned because I  would consider this expensive if so.

I tried to use tcpdump but traffic is to much and to cryptic to tell.

Answer (score 9):

I had a quick look at the [Node.js implementation of verifyIdToken on Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/fc45c4f5da404e21934cbd9f5a4e7116cb744f0a/src/auth/token-generator.ts#L140).

As far as I can see the only roundtrip it does is to [fetch the public keys](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/fc45c4f5da404e21934cbd9f5a4e7116cb744f0a/src/auth/token-generator.ts#L210) for the certs, which it only does if they're expired. Most of the other work are parameter checks and of course the [actual verification of the token](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/blob/master/verify.js).

So from what I can tell there should not be a 1:1 relation between the number of incoming verification requests and the number of outgoing network requests.